# RibbonApplicationMenuItem has wrong CurrentItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, currentitem

I've got an RibbonApplicationMenuItem with SubItems of the same Kind. The SubItems are added by Code.

After selecting a RibbonApplicationMenuItem the wrong currentItem is shown while handling the click event.

CurrentItem is always the first element in in my Collection of RibbonApplicationMenuItems.

```
 private void ApplicationOpenPileList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
     RibbonApplicationMenuItem SourceApplicationMenu = null;
     RibbonApplicationMenuItem SenderApplicationMenu = null;
     Pile currentPile = null;

     if (e.OriginalSource != null) {
        if (sender is RibbonApplicationMenuItem && e.OriginalSource is RibbonApplicationMenuItem) {
           SenderApplicationMenu = sender as RibbonApplicationMenuItem;
           SourceApplicationMenu = e.OriginalSource as RibbonApplicationMenuItem;               
        }                                   
     }
  }
```

SourceApplicationMenu contains the clicked MenuItem, but my connected Object is missing.
SenderApplicationMenu contains the corrospondig ParentMenuItem whith a property called CurrentItem.

The Event is assigned in XAML Code of the ribbonwindow for the main element:

```
        <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Resources\Icons\Scanner.ico">
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Neu" ImageSource="Resources\Icons\report_add.png"/>
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Öffnen" ImageSource="Resources\Icons\open_folder.png"  Name="ApplicationOpenPileList" Click="ApplicationOpenPileList_Click" />                                        
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Dokumententypen" ImageSource="Resources\Icons\application_form.png" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Click="RibbonApplicationMenuItem_Click"  />
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Schließen" ImageSource="Resources\Icons\cross.png"/>
            </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```

In this case CurrentItem always contains the first SubItem with the correspondig object.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Please post where you are assigning the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was quite simple.

The SubItems hasn't got a Click Event handler, so the events were routed to the upper handler.

I've now implement the handler for each Item and everything is fine.